# select all products and their category names

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this :

`product(id_product,reference,category_id)`

and

`category(category_id,category)`

How can I output every product plus his category name?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to join two tables like:

```
SELECT id_product, reference, c.category_id, category
FROM product p INNER JOIN category c
ON p.category_id = c.category_id
```

Comment: More on SQL joins, for the interested: https://i.imgur.com/4LS7D0k.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `left join` for that 
 (which outputs all products and categories if they exists)

```
select p.*, 
       c.category
from product p
left join category c
on p.category_id = c.category_id
```